# Angular 6- Ag-grid rid-overlay-component

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I want to implement javascript-grid-overlay-component with my angular 6 code but it is not working nor giving any error, Is there any issue with the ag-grid? the documentation is also not very clear. I have implemented the same as given on : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/

My component.ts code for overlay is:

```
import { OverlayComponent } from './overlay/overlay.component';

constructor(
this.frameworkComponents = {
  OverlayComponent: OverlayComponent
};
this.loadingOverlayComponent = "OverlayComponent";
this.loadingOverlayComponentParams = { loadingMessage: "One moment please..." };)
```

In HTML same value passed to ag-grid

```
[loadingOverlayComponent]="loadingOverlayComponent"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Can you add a fiddle with what you have tried so far. And what you need to achieve even more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, what you're attempting is inherently impossible. GridReady provides you with the reference of the GridApi which you need to prompt the overlay; What you're trying to attempt clearly defeats the purpose of the loading overlay.

The loading overlay is meant to be used when the table loads data into the rows.